# extracting array inside an object thats inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

hi guys I'm trying to extract data from this:

```
1) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
__v: 0
​​
_id: "5ba96b8ebffd923734090df4"
​​
formID: "5ba96b83bffd923734090df0"
​​
inputArr: Array(3) [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
​​
labelArr: Array(3) [ "label1", "label2", "label3" ]
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I need to get to the array inside the data, which is this.state.inputData (what you see above is the content),

I tried

```
const labels = inputDataArr[0].labelArr.map((r, index) => {
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <th>{index}</th>
          <th>{r[index]}</th>
        </tr>
      );
```

but I get item undefined, anybody knows why?

EDIT : additional problem rendering :

```
renderData(i) {
    const { inputDataArr } = this.state;
    return (
      !!inputDataArr.length &&
      inputDataArr[i].inputArr.map((input, index) => (
        <th key={index}>{input}</th>
      ))
    );
  }
  countLength() {
    const { inputDataArr } = this.state;
    return !!inputDataArr.length && inputDataArr[0].inputArr.length;
  }
  runThrough() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.countLength; i++) return this.renderData(i);
  }
  render() {
    const data = this.runThrough();
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <table>
          <tr>{this.renderLabels()}</tr>
          {data}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have mistaken `r` in your mapping as an array, it is actually one of the `inputArr` values.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand, inputDataArr is an array, I take the [0] one which is an object, and I go for the array which is  labelArr

Comment: The html here `<th>{r[index]}</th>` should be `<th>{r}</th>`

Comment: I get this error : this.state.inputDataArr.labelArr is undefined even tho this.state.inputDataArr is defined and I can see the structure that I posted above.

Comment: Try `const labels = inputDataArr.labelArr` instead of `inputDataArr[0]` incase it is not an array.

Comment: tried that I got inputDataArr.labelArr is not defined..

Comment: Do you want to map the state, then render the all labels in `labelArr` arrays?

Comment: @Devserkan yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the same example from your other question. Not quite sure this suits you as it is, maybe you need to change and think about it a little bit.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputDataArr: [
      {
        formID: "3",
        inputArr: [ "value1", "value2" ],
        labelArr: [ "label1", "label2" ],
      },
      {
        formID: "3",
        inputArr: [ "value3", "value4" ],
        labelArr: [ "label3", "label4" ],
      },
    ],
  }


  renderLabels() {
    const { inputDataArr } = this.state;
    return !!inputDataArr.length && inputDataArr[ 0 ].labelArr.map( ( label, index ) =>
      ( <tr key={label}>
        <th>{index}</th>
        <th>{label}</th>
        </tr> ) );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          {this.renderLabels()}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update after comments**

After learning that you are getting the data via an async operation, I've added a small condition to the `renderLabels` method. Now it looks for if the array's length returns `true`:

```
return !!inputDataArr.length && inputDataArr[ 0 ]
```

This is a mix of logical operators and React's rendering logic. Why I use `!!inputDataArr.length` instead of `inputDataArr.length`?

Normally, in logical operators, if the first condition is `0` then it does not pass the second part.

```js
const num = 0;

num && console.log( "passed the second part" );
```

As you can see it never passes the second part. This is because `0` means `false` here.

React ignores rendering if a value is `undefined` or `false` or `null`. But it renders if a value is `0` :)

Let's see:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    num: 0,
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.num && <p>Render me</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is similar to your situation. In the first render array's length is `0`. So, if we use this:

```
return inputDataArr.length && inputDataArr[ 0 ]
```

it renders a `0`. What we want here is ignore the rendering. So if we use logical NOT operator twice we get a `false` here and React ignores rendering. Why we get `false`?

Since `0` means `false`, `!!false` again evaluated to `false`. Then, React ignores rendering and we are safe from the error that you provided in your question.

When the data lands your app, in the second render this time array's length is greater than `0`, let's say `2`. `!!2` evaluates to `true` then React renders the second part of the condition, your label array.

You can write your condition like this if you want:

```
renderLabels() {
  const { inputDataArr } = this.state;
  if (inputDataArr.length > 1) {
    return inputDataArr[0].labelArr.map((label, index) => (
      <tr key={label}>
        <th>{index}</th>
        <th>{label}</th>
      </tr>
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but the last question I just filtered the once I dont need, I get an array of objects with the ID of 3, so for this example all of the objects have the ID of 3, and all of their labelArr is the same, I just want to make a table containing all of those labels in the array.

Comment: How same? All of them are like `[ "label1", "label2", "label3" ]`? So this is the only array you want to map?

Comment: all of the objects have the same array that contains label1 label2 label3, and I want to map it for the headers.

Comment: So, mapping one of them is enough?

Comment: Its really late so I might see your answer tomorrow, so thank you in advance!

Comment: In  a minute, it is also very late here :)

Comment: hey devserkan thank you for your answer, but thats exactly what I did and I get that inputDataArr[0].labelArr is undefined

Comment: I've updated my answer again. This is because probably you are getting the data via an async operation. In the first render `inputDataArr` is undefined. So, we can't get a property from `undefined`. I've changed the `renderLabels` method according to this condition.

Comment: wow it works, but can you explain what you did here? why is there a double ! ! ?

Comment: @AlexAlex, I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation , but might I ask is this standard procedure to deal with async function? i'm simply rendering it with willMount, should I use a different method or thats fine?

Comment: If you are asking the lifecycle method by saying "standard" then use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in the v17. So, yes using the proper lifecycle method then rendering your data conditionally is a pretty standard procedure. But, the condition is not standard here. It changes according to your data. Sometimes you check the length of an array, but sometimes this is not enough and you check for a property of an object to be safe. This totally depends on your data and how you render it.

Comment: I mean I've never seen anything like it, from loading state with componentWillMount/didMount, is it common to do so? or it can be avoided ? i'll rephrase the question, using the condition you mentioned is it common to check if the state was updated? or is there a better way? because I have never seen someone checking the code like that, is it common practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180747/discussion-between-devserkan-and-alex-alex).

Comment: In case you can't come to the chat discussion, [here is conditional rendering part](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) of the official documentation. If `!!` part confused you I am going to add a simpler `if` method in a minute.

Comment: could I count on your knowledge once more? I'm trying to print the inputArr so it will be below the headers for each item in the inputDataArr, I posted my code below and it doesn't work, would you mind looking at it?

Comment: Do not widen your old questions like that :) Ask a new question and try to give all the details there. Also, do not bother with `for loops`, use `map` or other methods. I won't be here for a while but when you ask a new question and give good details people will try to help.